# Writing the name of a Windows file by using LaTeX

Tags: windows

I'm wondering if there is a way to write the name of a windows file by using LaTeX. I looked for a solution online, but without success. For example, for a pdf file, I'd like to write the name in LaTeX and the extension should be .pdf.

Comment: Trying to clarify the question: (1) You are writing LaTeX on Windows and would like to have some code in the .tex file that prints **its own filename** (or the name of the resulting pdf), **automatically**, in the pdf document? (2) You would like to **manually type** an **arbitrary** file name in LaTeX and have it displayed in a specific format? Or (3) some other request?

Comment: Hello @marquinho I'm going to explain better the question: imagine to create a new .txt file on your desktop and to rename it pippo.txt. My goal is to rename it by inserting a LaTeX formula in its name, for example x^2.txt or \int{x^2}.txt etc

Comment: your question is very hard to understand and does not appear to be about latex a all but about the windows filesystem are you just asking if it is possible to have a file with name `x^2.pdf` in Windows?

Comment: Hi @DavidCarlisle yes this is my question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: why do you need to ask here (it's mostly off topic here) just right click on a file in the windows file explorer and rename the file, if you try an illegal name (eg with `"`) it will tell you, if the name is legal the file will be renamed

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Maybe someone knows a workaround to write the name of a file in LaTeX (which is for sure illegal) by modifying something in Windows. I posted the question here because on other forums it's difficult to find latex experts. Do you think that I should migrate the question?

Comment: I do not think the question is related to latex at all is it? are you not just asking if `^` , `{` and `}` are legal in windows filenames, You can not use `\ ` as that is the directory separator.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, it's not directly related to latex, but indirectly because the goal is to write in latex a file name in Windows. For this reason I used only the Windows tag.

Comment: Then [superuser](https://superuser.com/) might be [a better fit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209397/where-do-i-ask-questions-about-the-windows-os).

Comment: given that `a\log b` is the file `log b` in the folder `a` it is clear that you can only use a very limited subset (you can have a file `x^2.pdf` if you want though as far as I can see